# CKEditor inline code snippets highlighting

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, code-snippets

I am having a problem integrating the [prism](http://ckeditor.com/addon/prism) code snippets syntax highlighter with the inline version of `CKEditor` I already added the required JS and css files in the `<head>` tag but but the highlight doesn't seem to be working

**Note:** the highlighting is working fine withe the full editor version ( 'replace' instead of 'inline')

here is my code:

```
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/codesnippet/lib/highlight/styles/arta.css">
<script src="ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/codesnippet/lib/highlight/highlight.pack.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
        <h1>Hello world!</h1>
        <p>I'm an instance of <a href="http://ckeditor.com">CKEditor</a>.</p>
    </div>
</body>
<script language="JavaScript">
    (function() {
        CKEDITOR.inline('editor')
    })();
</script>

</html>
```

and this is what I am getting:
[image: Screenshot of my CKEditor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what is causing the problem it seems that  Prism Highlighter is not handling the auto-loading of Prism JS and CSS files ,the solution is to those two lines:

```
      <script src="plugins/prism/lib/prism/prism_patched.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/prism/lib/prism/prism_patched.min.css">
```